# average number of opportunities per account

Tags: apex

I know that there can be some issues with regards to having more than 10k children for a parent. I am wondering if you can tell on average how many opportunities per account you normally have? I am working on a system that is really good and fast but cannot handle more than 10 k opportunities on accounts.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with SOQL alone, and even if it were, it sounds like the type of query that would run over the 50,000 row limit per transaction. There are almost always some creative solutions out there, but can you tell us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

Simply create a roll-up summary field on the Account object, counting all Opportunity records, then you can run an Account report to find the average and maximum number of opportunities.

---

You can also find the largest accounts by running a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID), AccountId
FROM Opportunity
GROUP BY AccountId
ORDER BY COUNT(ID) Desc
LIMIT 10
```

Note that if this goes over 50,000 rows, you will get an error in Apex Code. If that happens, you can use an API tool to do the query instead, such the Query tab in the Developer Console.

Comment: If you are using `Reports`, I believe you don't even need a `Rollup Summary` field.